# mongoDB aggregation $lookup query

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, aggregation-framework

I've got 3 collections in my MongoDB database named users, events, rsvps.

rsvp documents store 3 fields: userId(objectId of user), eventId(objectId of event) and, a status.
now I want to to create an events route(/events/rsvpd/:userId) which returns all the events with the userId passed in query params and which has status=confirmed(note: status is enum: ["confirmed", "rejected"]).
I want to do this with aggregation using $match and $lookup.

```
const getRsvpdEvents = async (userId) => {
  const allRsvpdEvents = await Event.aggregate([{
    $lookup: {
      from: "rsvps",
      localField: "_id",
      foreignField: "eventId",
      as: "rsvpd"
    }
  }])
  return allRsvpdEvents
}
```

sample document of events:-

```
{"_id":{"$oid":"621cf72bc012e83049b33a7c"},"title":"test event","startDate":{"$date":"2022-02-28T16:22:01.865Z"},"endDate":{"$date":"2022-02-28T16:22:01.865Z"},"createdAt":{"$date":"2022-02-28T16:24:11.324Z"},"updatedAt":{"$date":"2022-02-28T16:24:11.324Z"},"__v":0}
```

sample rsvps document:-

```
{"_id":{"$oid":"621d1df837e2d26d86c04eed"},"eventId":{"$oid":"621cf72bc012e83049b33a7c"},"userId":{"$oid":"621a708284694853f8c62f95"},"status":"rejected","__v":0,"updatedAt":{"$date":"2022-03-01T13:04:57.170Z"}}
```

sample users document:-

```
{"_id":{"$oid":"621a708284694853f8c62f95"},"name":"yasar","email":"xyz@domainz.com","mobileNumber":"767500","weight":70,"height":2,"bmi":17.5,"createdAt":{"$date":"2022-02-26T18:25:06.123Z"},"updatedAt":{"$date":"2022-02-27T07:59:00.984Z"},"__v":0}
```

I'm trying this but don't know what to do next, please help.
FYI here Event is a mongoose model on which I'm using aggregate.

Comment: Can you share sample documents of all collections? Just need to clarify where the status is present - in event doc or rsvp

Comment: added the events, rsvps, and users sample document